# Pre-fill Form, then Save to PDF

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, pdf-generation

I am relatively new to VBA and am learning as I go - would really appreciate if someone could shed light on a dilemma I've been stuck on for weeks.

I have a few Excel files, each with 2 sheets ("Form" & "Details"). Cells in the "Form" sheet are filled out based on the list of values in "Details" (e.g. name, surname, date etc.) to pre-fill automatically (via vlookup etc.).

I have, until now, had a macro assigned to the file to print out each new "Form" on a different page, as below.

```
Sub PrintForm()
  Dim i As Long
  Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

    Set ws1 = Sheets("Details")
    Set ws2 = Sheets("Form")

    '   2 assumes a header row - use 1 if there isn't one
    For i = 2 To ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        With ws2
            '   Populate the Forms sheet with employee names
            .Range("B2").Value = ws1.Cells(i, "A").Value
            .PrintOut

        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

This code has been working fine thus far, however, instead of printing out about 100 "Form" sheets per week, I've been trying to figure out how to save each of these "Forms" to PDF and saving it to a folder (essentially printing each form, but as a digital copy).

I am halfway there (I think). When running the code below, it works perfectly on one file (printing about 7 forms). But in another file, with a larger "Details" sheet, it returns either a "400" message with a red cross or runs only the first 20 values (only sometimes). Am not sure what this means or how I can fix it.

```
Sub PrintForm()
  Dim i As Long
  Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

    Set ws1 = Sheets("Details")
    Set ws2 = Sheets("Form")

    '   2 assumes a header row - use 1 if there isn't one
    For i = 2 To ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        With ws2
            '   Populate the Forms sheet with employee names
            .Range("B2").Value = ws1.Cells(i, "A").Value

            .ExportAsFixedFormat _
                Type:=x1TypePDF, _
                Filename:="C:\Archive\Forms\" & .Range("B2") & ".pdf", _
                Quality:=x1QualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
        End With
    Next i

End Sub
```

Would appreciate any input. Let me know if there is anything I can do to explain the issue further.

Comment: Your second macro works fine, i tested it and produced 200 .pdf files. Did you try to look up what a 400 error is?

Comment: Problem was in file name - solution updated accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

I've troubleshooted the issue by cross-referencing the worksheet that already works (the file that prints 7 forms to PDF).

Have adjusted the code to **start off with Sub PrintForms()** [plural, not the singular Sub PrintForm() in the initial code].

Have done test run successfully for 7 forms printed to PDF to my designated folder.

Let's hope this was the issue and holds out for 40+ files! :)

**UPDATE:**

It didn't actually hold out for 40+ files - the error was in the return value for "B2", which included restricted characters - so the file could not save automatically.

I've fixed it as per the code below, replacing every restricted character with a space. This is currently running well for 40+ files.

```
Sub PrintForms()
Dim i As Long
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

    Set ws1 = Sheets("Details")
    Set ws2 = Sheets("Form")

    '   2 assumes a header row - use 1 if there isn't one
    For i = 2 To ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        With ws2
            '   Populate the Forms sheet with employee names
            .Range("B2").Value = ws1.Cells(i, "A").Value
            .ExportAsFixedFormat _
                Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                Filename:="C:\Folder1\Subfolder1\" & Replace(Replace(Replace(.Range("B2").Value, "?", ""), "/", ""), "*", "").Value & ".pdf", _
                Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
        End With

End Sub
```

Comment: You are saying that changing the name of your macro fixed the macro? This is not an answer; the name of your sub does nothing to effect how your code runs, you could call it, `Sub ManualevacuationofForm()` or anything else you want, and your code will work.